# ScrollPane JavaFX - запретить скролл

Tags: javafx

Как в ScrollPane запретить появление горизонтального скролла?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Посмотрите в сторону метода [setHbarPolicy](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/ScrollPane.html#setHbarPolicy-javafx.scene.control.ScrollPane.ScrollBarPolicy-.)

```
scrollPane.setHbarPolicy(ScrollPane.ScrollBarPolicy.NEVER)
```